# Crystal Report HTML Text how to creat empty space on Formula FIeld

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

```
{RELATIONSHIP.RELATIONS_NAME}+ "    " +"<i>"+{RELATIONSHIP.PARENT_SUFFIX}+"</i>"
```

crystal Report

I create space before "`<i>`" but I do not see the space when texted, How can I appropriately code that I can create empty space. I am using HTML Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `Text Interpretation` setting of the formula field is set to `HTML`, then multiple consecutive spaces ar printed as one single space.

To print more than one space add `nbsp;` for each additional space.

```
{RELATIONSHIP.RELATIONS_NAME}+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +"<i>"+RELATIONSHIP.PARENT_SUFFIX}+"</i>"
```